# Display the validation Messages in ToolTips using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

How to display  the Validation messages in a tool Tip. These messages are the Client side validation messages.

[image]

I want to display this message in the tool tip. I used the below method earlier to show required fields but I have to display custom validation.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $(document).tooltip({
                items: ".input-validation-error",
                content: function () {
                    return $(this).attr('data-val-required');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is my View

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.CREW_TYPE)
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.CREW_TYPE)
```

Comment: what kind of custom validation do  you want to display? On different event or just different message?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987109/how-to-display-jqueryui-validation-error-message-in-jqueryui-tooltip    Try this