# mvc4 and display validation errors like tooltips

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm struggling to find solutions which should display mvc4 app validation errors inside razor view as tooltip messages instead inline using span class.

I would rather not change validation logic so I would like to keep existing mvc4 validation logic using Model and it's DataAnnotations attributes.

I've found [this solution](http://www.garethelms.org/2012/01/jquery-form-error-plugin/)
but this again requires adding additional script code inside razor page where validation should be done.

If anyone has advice or need further clarification of the problem please address it.

Thank you

**Update:
I've found this solution which works nice although I need one more adjustment, 
validation errors are presented inside tooltip on mouse over control, how to display it always on validation error (not just on mouse hover)?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987109/how-to-display-jqueryui-validation-error-message-in-jqueryui-tooltip

Answer (score 0):

Please use Validation Engine js, this works with the MVC validation, all you have to do is just add a script line on the page.
https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine